# GIT : Which way is better, directly push from branches or merging with master and then push?

Tags: git, github, merge, push, git-pull

I am learning GIT these days, moved from svn to git.
Can anyone help me figure out which is the good practice in case below.

Suppose I am working on two issues. I have created 2 branches to work.
branches: issue1 and issue2

**Approach 1**

I can directly pull latest codes to my branch issue1 or push to origin master by commands

Currently on branch issue1 :

Pull from origin master `git pull origin master`

Push to origin master `git push origin issu1:master`

**Approach 2**

Merge branch issue1 after fixing in it and push to origin master.

Currently on branch master
`git merge issue1` then
`git push` (push to origin master)

So I want to know If I go with approach 1 I will never need to merge with my local master and push.
Which is the good way to go? What is the difference between this two approaches?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't push from a feature branch to a remote master (if that's what approach 1 suggests).

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Specify what you mean when you say you are merging something (what with what) and when you are pulling (what are you pulling to, pushing (where are you pushing from), etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1** seems to be better when there are other team members, that should review a change in a branch and make the merge.
**Approach 2** is better in other cases.

There are many branching models out there. See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/

PS: As @choroba already mentioned it seems to be a bad advise to push from a local feature branch to the remote master.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have finished working on an issue, you no longer need the branch. Like @user3751845 said, Approach 1 is good for collaborating with a team. Otherwise, the new branch is unnecessary, so go with **Approach 2**.

(first answer on Stack Overflow! woo!)